# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException ao tentar reproduzir som no angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando reproduzir um som no angular, mas estou recebendo dois erros.

O primeiro:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException
>       push../src/app/components/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.informaNovaNotificacao

O segundo:

> GET http://localhost:4200/..%2F..%2F..%2Fassets%2Fsom_notificacao.mp3
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Eu tentei:

```
informaNovaNotificacao(estado: boolean){
    this.novaNotificacao = estado;
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = encodeURIComponent("../../../assets/som_notificacao.mp3");
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
}
```

Se eu retirar o encodeURIComponent eu recebo apenas o primeiro erro de DOMException, mas meu som não é reproduzido.

Comment: Com o segundo erro o aúdio é executado ?

Comment: @VictorHenrique não

Comment: O Segundo é um erro de requisição. Me parece que você esta fazendo uma requisição pra string que você passou.